# Cognos Prompt parameter

Tags: cognos

I have report with prompt includes parameter. I made those parameter as required but on the prompt page made them optional. I made them this way because when I make the parameter optional if the user didn't choose it will show all the thing.

Now it show another prompt page after the one I created requesting to choose the other parameter. I did read this can be solved by if condition. I made this equation but i get errors not sure if the logic wrong or way been written.

```
IF ( [BUSINESS VIEW].[All Business View].[STAGES] in ?STAGES1? ) THEN  ( [BUSINESS VIEW].[All Business View].[STAGES] in ?STAGES1? ) ELSE ( [BUSINESS VIEW].[All Business View].[STAGES] includes ('Arrival announced'))
```

Appreciate the help guys many thanks!

Comment: it gave me this error
V5 syntax error found in expression "[BUSINESS VIEW].[All Business View].[STAGES] in 'Arrival announced'
", invalid token "'Arrival announced'" found after "[BUSINESS VIEW].[All Business View].[STAGES] in ".


should i replace #prompt with prompt page name it's name is "Prompt page1"

Comment: What is the type of [BUSINESS VIEW].[All Business View].[STAGES]?

Answer (score 4):

Try something like

```
[BUSINESS VIEW].[All Business View].[STAGES] in (#promptmany('STAGES1','string','''Arrival announced''')#)
```

Comment: This is the right approach but whenever you use 'in' you should use the promptmany() function instead of prompt().